# throwIndexOutOfBoundsException in updateOomAdjLocked()

Tags: android, frameworks

In my tests I see the following exception in updateOomAdjLocked() of ActivityManagerService:

```
// java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 27, size is 27
//  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
//  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
//  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateOomAdjLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:13880)
//  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateLruProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:1904)
//  at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:647)
//  at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startSpecificActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:803)
```

Problematic code seems is the following (line 13850 for Android 4.2.2 r1.2):

```
final ArrayList<ProcessRecord> mLruProcesses
    = new ArrayList<ProcessRecord>();
{...}

final void updateOomAdjLocked() {
    {...}
    final int N = mLruProcesses.size();
    for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
        ProcessRecord app = mLruProcesses.get(i);
        {...}
    }
```

If mLruProcesses.remove was called while in the loop, then mLruProcesses.get(i) for i=N accessed a non-existing index, triggering an exception.

I know very little about Android services so far, so my question is if this code needs to be reenterable, perhaps by making some of the operations thread-safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could verify that the size of `mLruProcess.size()` is still equal to `N` within your loop.

```
final boolean updateOomAdjLocked() {
   {...}
   final int N = mLruProcess.size();
   for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
       if(N != mLruProcess.size()) {
           //Do something accordingly, in this case return false
           return false;
       }

       ProcessRecord app = mLruProcess.get(i);
       {...}
   }

   {...}       

   return true;
}
```

Add some logic where you call this function, if it returns false try to have it call the function again. Otherwise, you could put `mLruProcess` in a `Synchronized` block which means that it can be accessed in only one concurrent thread. The `Synchronized` keyword is blocking, which means any code that tries to access `mLruProcess` in another thread will be blocked until the current thread is done with mLruProcess.

If you don't like to, or can't use blocking code, try using an `AtomicBoolean` as shown here:

[When to use synchronized in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494856/when-to-use-synchronized-in-java)

Set the `AtomicBoolean` whenever you change the object stored in `mLruProcess` and then check that `AtomicBoolean` everywhere you need to access the objects stored in `mLruProcess`.

Comment: OP's snippet comes from the [Android source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java). I don't think he can modify those internals, rather he's looking for solutions to avoid this (seemingly unintended) concurrency issue.

Comment: Thanks, David and Mattias. Yes, there are a few ways to avoid this exception and each one has to be evaluated for not breaking the OOM adj logic. Mostly I was wondering if this is supposed to be re-enterable code that is aware of the concurrency issues. In the way it is done by Google, doesn't seem like it is. The fact that I'm hitting this exception, seems it has to be.

Comment: Because this method is declared `final`, it can't be modified. At the very least the OP could look into `AtomicBoolean`s to try and solve his/her issues.